# Why does setting a property crash when self is nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, null

My app has been crashing on this line of code in some rare situations

```
self.dataBuffer = nil;
```

That property is declared as

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData* dataBuffer;
```

To me the line looks perfectly safe. I thought the dot syntax is just shorthand for `[self setDataBuffer:nil]` and the only weird thing that could happen here is `self == nil`, but then the selector should be ignored, not crash. However wrapping the line in `if (self != nil)` seems to prevent the crash. So apparently it isn't safe?

Why?

---

In case it matters, this is actually in a (very old version of a) library, [MQTTClient](https://github.com/novastone-media/MQTT-Client-Framework/blob/7212b886dd70559006dfa442fd56b56b4dfb64da/MQTTClient/MQTTClient/MQTTDecoder.m#L172), related to [this crash.](https://github.com/novastone-media/MQTT-Client-Framework/issues/325)

Comment: Could you say more about _where_ this code is? You should not be messaging `self` at all in `dealloc` for example, so it seems worth asking whether by any chance you are doing that.

Comment: The way you set it should not cause the crash - your assumptions are correct. Weird things could happen if you overload ```setDataBuffer``` but only if ```self``` is not null and you'd know about it. The problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: Also one wonders how we got into a situation where our code is running but we are nil. This seems to suggest a concurrency issue where we are being preserved behind our own backs.

Comment: The crash in the picture you posted from 2017 features `objc_msgSend` on the stack, which is usually about calling a non-existent method.  What does your crash look like?  (Error message, stack trace...)

Comment: Yes I also suspect concurrent access ...

Comment: @PhillipMills yes it's the same one. SIGSEGV at `libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend` called from `MQTTDecoder.m` on the line where `dataBuffer` is set

Comment: @matt this crash seems to be internal to the MQTTClient library. We can get the crash to happen semi-consistently by having the MQTT server send a reset message. Since other people's apps seem to be having the exact same crash (and the bug is still open on github) it seems unlikely that it is due to us misusing the library in some way.